Select column name that has the maximum value (only list the column names once in the SQL query)
Table name: employment_by_industry

https://dbfiddle.uk/hkwDS2DS
For each row, I want to select the column name that has the maximum value:


What is the most succinct way to do that in PostgreSQL, with the column names only being listed once in the SQL query?
For example, this is how it would be done in Oracle:
select objectid, max(col_name) keep (dense_rank first order by col_val desc) max_col_name
from employment_by_industry
unpivot (
  col_val
  for col_name in (
    agr_forest_fish, mining_quarry, mfg, electric, water_sew  --cols only listed once
  )
)
group by objected

https://dbfiddle.uk/DeaRoikf

Is the number of objectids small and known in advance or can it change? And what do you do in the case of ties?

And why do you have AGR_FOREST_FISH twice?

@Vérace The OBJECTIDs are relatively small, yes. Thousands, not millions. The values are static in a table; they won’t change. AGR_FOREST_FISH is listed twice in the desired output table because it is the column with the highest count in both row 1 and 3.

No need to explode the values out and regroup them. Can do https://dbfiddle.uk/ZdJhvNZC (though ignores the "only list once")

So do you have your answer?

Basic query
You can use a VALUES expression to unpivot, like Martin already suggested. Plus, if any value column can be null use DESC NULLS LAST, and add a tiebreaker to ORDER BY to make the result deterministic:
SELECT e.objectid
    , (SELECT t.industry
       FROM  (
          VALUES
            (e.agr_forest_fish, 'agr_forest_fish')
          , (e.mining_quarry  , 'mining_quarry')
          , (e.mfg            , 'mfg')
          -- ...
          ) t (val, industry)
       ORDER  BY t.val DESC NULLS LAST, t.industry  -- industry as tiebreaker
       LIMIT  1)
FROM  employment_by_industry e;

Don't spell out column names
You ask to ...

only list the column names once in the SQL query

if you look up column names in the system dynamically, you don't have to list them at all.
Well, you have to mention objectid once to exclude it (or even avoid that and look up the PK column instead).
Base query:
SELECT attname
FROM   pg_catalog.pg_attribute
WHERE  attrelid = 'employment_by_industry'::regclass
AND    attnum > 0
AND    NOT attisdropped
AND    attname <> 'objectid'  -- exclude more?

Concatenate that into the query from above - pretty format completely optional - and execute the generated query.
Demonstrating \gexec in psql:
test=> SELECT 'SELECT e.objectid
test'>     , (SELECT t.industry
test'>        FROM  (
test'>           VALUES
test'>            '
test-> || string_agg(format('(e.%1$I , %1$L)', attname), E'\n          , ')
test-> || '
test'>           ) t (val, industry)
test'>        ORDER  BY t.val DESC NULLS LAST, t.industry
test'>        LIMIT  1
test'>        )
test'> FROM   public.employment_by_industry e'
test-> FROM   pg_attribute
test-> WHERE  attrelid = 'public.employment_by_industry'::regclass
test-> AND    attnum > 0
test-> AND    NOT attisdropped
test-> AND    attname <> 'objectid'\gexec

 objectid |    industry     
----------+-----------------
        1 | agr_forest_fish
        2 | mfg
        3 | agr_forest_fish
(3 rows)

Or write a (temporary) function and execute it:
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION pg_temp.f_maxcol()
  RETURNS TABLE (objectid int, industry text)
  LANGUAGE plpgsql PARALLEL SAFE AS
$func$
BEGIN   
   RETURN QUERY EXECUTE
   -- RAISE NOTICE '%',   -- print to debug
   (
   SELECT 'SELECT e.objectid
    , (SELECT t.industry
       FROM  (
          VALUES
           '
   || string_agg(format('(e.%1$I , %1$L)', attname), E'\n          , ')
   || '
          ) t (val, industry)
       ORDER  BY t.val DESC NULLS LAST, t.industry
       LIMIT  1)
FROM   public.employment_by_industry e'
   FROM   pg_catalog.pg_attribute
   WHERE  attrelid = 'public.employment_by_industry'::regclass
   AND    attnum > 0
   AND    NOT attisdropped
   AND    attname <> 'objectid'
   );
END   
$func$;

Call:
SELECT * FROM pg_temp.f_maxcol();

fiddle
Or just use two steps: first generate, then execute.
Related:

Function to return dynamic set of columns for given table

